# Arcgis Map : Get Current Location Error , Not displaying my current location

Tags: java, android, dictionary, arcgis, esri

Hie,

I tried this sample code that one of the person who gave me this in my other question in stack overflow. I tried using this code but when i run the applicationn, it doesnt locate my current device and it doesnt even display a dot of my location .. The code does not give me any red underline errors but i am unable to locate the current location i am at.

What did i miss out? is there anyone who has a sample working source code file that i can download from to get my current device location??

the codes i  used is as followed,

This is my **MainActivity.class**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

MapView mMapView;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mMapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
     mMapView.addLayer(new ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer(
         "http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Topo_Map/MapServer"));
    mMapView = new MapView(this);

    LocationResult locationResult = new LocationResult(){
        @Override
        public void gotLocation(Location loc){

        }
    };  
    MyLocation mylocation = new MyLocation();
    mylocation.getLocation(this, locationResult);

}
```

This is **MyLocation.java**

```
public class MyLocation {
Timer timer1;
LocationManager lm;
LocationResult locationResult;
boolean gps_enabled=false;
boolean network_enabled=false;

public boolean getLocation(Context context, LocationResult result)
{
    //I use LocationResult callback class to pass location value from MyLocation to user code.
    locationResult=result;
    if(lm==null)
        lm = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    //exceptions will be thrown if provider is not permitted.
    try{gps_enabled=lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);}catch(Exception ex){}
    try{network_enabled=lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);}catch(Exception ex){}

    //don't start listeners if no provider is enabled
    if(!gps_enabled && !network_enabled)
        return false;

    if(gps_enabled)
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListenerGps);
    if(network_enabled)
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListenerNetwork);
    timer1=new Timer();
    timer1.schedule(new GetLastLocation(), 20000);
    return true;
}

LocationListener locationListenerGps = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        timer1.cancel();
        locationResult.gotLocation(location);
        lm.removeUpdates(this);
        lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerNetwork);
    }
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
};

LocationListener locationListenerNetwork = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        timer1.cancel();
        locationResult.gotLocation(location);
        lm.removeUpdates(this);
        lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerGps);
    }
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
};

class GetLastLocation extends TimerTask {
    @Override
    public void run() {
         lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerGps);
         lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerNetwork);

         Location net_loc=null, gps_loc=null;
         if(gps_enabled)
             gps_loc=lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
         if(network_enabled)
             net_loc=lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

         //if there are both values use the latest one
         if(gps_loc!=null && net_loc!=null){
             if(gps_loc.getTime()>net_loc.getTime())
                 locationResult.gotLocation(gps_loc);
             else
                 locationResult.gotLocation(net_loc);
             return;
         }

         if(gps_loc!=null){
             locationResult.gotLocation(gps_loc);
             return;
         }
         if(net_loc!=null){
             locationResult.gotLocation(net_loc);
             return;
         }
         locationResult.gotLocation(null);
    }
}

public static abstract class LocationResult{
    public abstract void gotLocation(Location location);
}
}
```

Comment: one suggestion for you. try to appreciate other people support by giving their answer upvote and mark the answer that helped you as accepted. In your profile you have asked 17 questions but never acknowledged any answers. If you continue like this people will stop helping you.

Answer (score 1):

You have to write the code for displaying a red dot in the gotLocation method which is currently empty. That is why you are not getting anything displayed on top of the map.